# PHP ordering arrays naturally

Tags: php

I would like to ask how could I order some array naturally?
In the older php versions natsort worked fine, but now it`s not the case. It skips spaces and messes up the natural order.
I found

> sort($list_items,SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

and

```
 usort($list_items, function($first, $second)  {
    if ($first == $second) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (strtolower($first) < strtolower($second)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Works better but they both have one problem: it puts the single words at the end of the list.
For ex. it would be:

- New York
- New

not

- New
- New York

Anyone would have a solution for this?
Thank you very much!

- Romania Yearbook
- Romania Ziar independent
- Romania

Comment: can you share your array?

Comment: no need to put complete array just put a sample portion of array which is not working with your expected output.

Comment: I put a list above but I`m still learning how to insert new lines (two spaces or list doesn`t seem to work).  Thank you!

Comment: Are you expecting this, which i have updated in my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting this? Here we are using [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function for Binary safe string comparison.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783029)

```
$array = array(
    "Romania Yearbook",
    "Romania Ziar independent",
    "Romaniai Elelmezezi Ipari Munkasok Egyesult",
    "Romaniai"
);
usort($array,function($str1, $str2){
    strcmp($str1, $str2);
});
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I changed the list a little bit from the first one, but the code does not work unfortunately... :( It has not effect on my code.

Comment: @RóbertBodnár Can you share that list?

Comment: I think I found the problem! My stupidity :)   

Actually it`s a list of pdf-s that when sorting have the extension .pdf... Then when I list them, I get rid of it... So the actual list would be with extension and "." will make the word to stick to the end...

Now I have to find a way to order without the extension :/ But that's another question...

Comment: sorry, I`m no programmer missed this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `array_multisort()` is what you need and it has `sorting type` as well.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_multisort.asp

Comment: Unfortunately does not work, it has the same problem and separates the small and capital letters too.

Answer (score 0):

please try with asort(array); it is used for sorting value by name

Comment: Same problem :( 
The single word ends up at the end not at the beginning.